# find a frequency of words in text file

Tags: c++

Please can anybody help me? I'm a beginner and I have a hard assignment.
I need to write a c++ program that does the following :

1. Ask the user to enter two text file the first one contains the text file, the second one contains a list of words in one column Regardless of their number like this:
   //output
   Enter the text file: text_file.txt
   Enter the keywords file: keywords_file.txt
2. Search for the keywords from the keywords file in the text file
3. Find the appearance of each word like this :

   ```
   system: 55 times
   analysis: 21 times
   ```
4. Then output in new text file (ofstream)

This is my code it's coded properly ..but it asks the user to enter the words..I want it to take the words from the input text file ..and show the output on the text file (ofstream)

**this is a part of keywords contents**
//they are as a list in the original file

- List item

model,
management,
e-commerce,
system,
cluster
infrastructure,
computer,
knowledge,
metadata,
process,
alter,
simulate,
stock,
inventory,
strategy,
plan,
historical,
deices,
exact,
Analyst,
break even point,
SWOT,
tactic,
develop,
prototype,
feasible,
Inferences,
busy,
cloud compute,
schema,
enterprise,
custom,
expert system,
structure,
data mine,
data warehouse,
organism,
data mart,
operate,
quality assure,
forecast,
report,

**this is a part of the book contents**

the circuit is characterised by long straights and chicanes. this means the carsâ€™ engines
are at full throttle for over 75% of the lap, a higher percentage than most other circuits.
the track requires heavier-than-average braking over a given lap, as the cars repeatedly
decelerate at the end of some of the worldâ€™sfasTest straights for the slow chicanes.
the chicanes are lined by rugged kerbs. riding over these hard is crucial for fast laps.
the long straights require small wings for minimum drag. this means lower downforce,
resulting in lower grip on corners and under braking, and less stability over bumps.
the main high-speed corners lesmo 1, lesmo 2 and parabolica are all right turns.
parts of the circuit are surrounded by trees, which means leaves can be blown
onto the track.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {

 ofstream ofs("output.txt");
 ofs << "Keywords " << endl;
 string kw_file;
 cout << "enter the file name :" << " ";
 getline(cin, kw_file);
 ifstream keywordFile(kw_file.c_str());
 string text_file;
 cout << "enter the file name :" << " ";
 getline(cin, text_file);
 ifstream textFile(text_file.c_str());
 if (!keywordFile.is_open() || !textFile.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "Error in opening files\n";
    return 1;
  }
 {//vector method
    size_t i = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> keywordVector;
    std::string keyword;
    while (keywordFile >> std::ws >> keyword) {
        keywordVector.push_back(keyword);
       
    }

    
    std::vector<int> countVector(keywordVector.size());
    std::string textWord;
    while (textFile >> std::ws >> textWord) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < keywordVector.size(); ++i) {
            if (keywordVector[i] == textWord) {
            
                countVector[i]++;
               

            }

        }

    }
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < keywordVector.size(); ++i) {
        ofs << "The number of times [" << keywordVector[i] << "] appears in 
  textFile is " << countVector[i] << '\n';

    }

 }

  keywordFile.clear(); textFile.clear();

 keywordFile.seekg(0);
 textFile.seekg(0);
```

}

Comment: Your `while(1)` won't ever exit. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/47dPP6e5d)

Comment: Also, just like `ifstream file(input_file.c_str());`, ask the user for another file and read it line by line and read in all the keywords.

Comment: could you help me rewrite the code? I'm really confused

Comment: 1. Accept the name of two files from the user. 2. Open these files and do error-check for whether they are closed etc. 3. Read the lines from file containing keywords into _something_ (think about what it could be). 4. Read the lines from the other `text_file.txt` and check if the kewords from Step#3 are present in these lines. Do these steps make sense to you?

Comment: yes, its make sense..i will do them step by step and edit the code according to them ..will you still with me tracking the code?

Comment: the part of reading words from keywords file its done by string dynamic code?

Comment: Let's move the discussion to the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231253/discussion-for-file-input). Comments aren't for long discussions.

Comment: i  cant move to chat ..i need 20 reputation to do it...can i make zoom meeting with you?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use zoom. We can continue in the comments. Please update your code and then tell the point where you are stuck. I'll keep track of the question. Also to answer _the part of reading words from keywords file its done by string dynamic code?_ , yes store the read in variables from the file into `std::string`

Comment: ok ,I will work on it

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ read word frequency".  There are already a plethora of issues about this topic or assignment.

Comment: I modified the code ..I tested the part that read the words input file and its worked. And I tested the part that read the text file and its worked...but the part of searching the word in the text file and find the counter its doesn't give me output. Also its doesn't give me error for (i = 0; i < file1.eof(); i++) { int position = 0; for (j = line.find(i); j < file.eof(); i = i + position) { position = line.find(j, i); if (position != string::npos) //if word is there in line { position += 1; i = counter; counter++; } }  @Zoso

Comment: @HaneenShtaya You are just reading in a single word from the `keywords.txt` file. You need to read in _all_ the keywords and then open the text file and search for those keywords. Also, are you allowed to use [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)? Go through the examples of this data structure and see if it gives you an idea of how to go about solving your problem?

Comment: yes im allowed to use it ,but I don't know hoe to use it, I will try it

Comment: I cant, do it...could you help me doing it @Zoso

Comment: @HaneenShtaya Does the answer help you?

Comment: Than you very much....you are gorgeous..its worked....also i understand it.

Comment: @HaneenShtaya In that case you can accept the answer to mark this question closed :).

Comment: i faced a problem later....the code make tokenizing to the both of text files and I don't want it to do that...also the code doesn't find the real time of appearances for the words

Comment: @HaneenShtaya What do you mean by tokenizing of both files? It's just reading the words from the file right?  It stores only the keywords. And what do you mean it doesn't update frequency? It doesn't give the correct count?

Comment: tokenizing mean that its split each word on its own line, yes its doesn't give the correct frequency, like the word system the correct answer of its appearance is 157,the code give it as 72 which is false

Comment: @HaneenShtaya Share a link to your code or edit the question to show your code.

Comment: @HaneenShtaya Also please share a link to both the keyword and text files. Maybe use pastebin or something

Comment: i can share them by answer the question?

Comment: i edit the code

Comment: @HaneenShtaya Yes, you can share the file contents in the question itself. If they are too big, then just paste a small part of the files and we can see what the files look like and what should be the output.

Comment: i do it. can you check the please

Comment: can we just use array list to solve  the problem?

Comment: @HaneenShtaya, when you mention `they are as a list in the original file`, I hope the words are on a single line each/space-separated and there are no commas in between, else the method of reading in the keywords would need to change.

Comment: Also @HaneenShtaya, none of the words appear in the content of the book from the list you shared. So, the program will always return 0. Try to narrow down the problem into something where you have a couple of sentences and there are keywords from the list which appear but the program doesn't count the correct instances. e.g. If list is `system analysis` and book has `This book deals with system analysis`, then the program should dump `system: 1 analysis: 1`. Basically create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: if i change the purpose of the program and the code ,would you help me? , like i want it to see if the word is exist or not without counting it ... also read the words from the input file each of them is on a single line ...the code read it as one line ,and then search for it each line in the text file...without split the words from each others ,cause in some cases in want to search for phrases

Comment: @HaneenShtaya I would but then this question needs to be closed. If you change the purpose (and possibly the code), it merits a different question altogether. My only thing is does my suggested solution work for your _initial prupose_? I'm not sure how much of a purpose change is that. Add a section to your question and let's see if it needs a different question. THis question has gone on far too long :)

Comment: i will post it like new post

Answer (score 2):

### Preliminary

Before even starting to solve this problem, let's think about what is actually required from this:

1. Read in the *keywords* from `keywords_file.txt`
2. Store these keywords in a data structure for later use.
3. Read in words from `text_file.txt`
4. Use the data structure from Step#2 to compare the words read in Step#3

Data structure simply refers to how your program stores the data that it works on. When you create an array such as

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

to later do some manipulations on, that too is a data structure.

### Choosing the Data Structure for the Problem

From the above steps, reading in words from the file is a simple problem to solve. The most pressing problem is to figure out the data structure in Step#2.

Let's try to start with a basic one: [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). We are going to use `vector` instead of arrays like in the C-language primarily for 2 reasons:

1. Fixed arrays are simple to handle and are the preferred data structure when we have fixed data. But in this problem, we have *dynamic* data because the number of words in the `keywords_file.txt` could vary. It's much easier to use `vector`s as dynamic arrays rather than C-style dynamic arrays because it's much easier to manage memory with `vector` than with a plain array.
2. We are using C++ and not C, so let's try to use the data structures available in the Standard Library of C++.

If we choose a `vector` as the data structure to store the words from `keywords_file.txt`, then we would also need a data strcture to store the count of each word which would be the number of times it's found in `text_file.txt`. We can again use a `vector` for this. We could have some code like (pseudo-code only)

1. Read in a keyword(using a `std::string`) from `keywords_file.txt`
2. Store it in a vector (using the [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) function) [Let's call this `vector` as `keywordVector`]
3. Repeat Step#1 and #2 until *all the words* from `keywords_file.txt` are read in and added to `keywordVector`.
4. Create another `vector` (let's call it `countVector` for storing the counts of the word which is of the same size as that of `keywordVector`.
5. Initialize all the values in `countVector` with 0.
6. Read in a word(again a `std::string`) from `text_file.txt`
7. Search for this word in the `vector`.
8. If the word is found in the `vector`, increment that word's count by increasing the count in `countVector` for that word, else ignore the word
9. Repeat Step#5 and Step#6 till *all the words* from `text_file.txt` are read in.

Note for Step#8, if word from `text_file.txt` matches with word at `keywordVector[i]`, then increment the value of the corresponding index in the `countVector` i.e. `++countVector[i]`

This should work for small programs and should solve the problem. Here's how the code would look like:

```
std::vector<std::string> keywordVector;//empty vector of strings
std::string keyword; //string to store each word read in from keywords_file.txt
while(keywordFile>>std::ws>>keyword) {//std::ws just ignores any whitespace
    keywordVector.push_back(keyword);
}

//create vector of same size as keywordVector to keep track of count
std::vector<int> countVector(keywordVector.size());
std::string textWord;
while(textFile>>std::ws>>textWord) {
    //Search through the keywordVector tocheck if any word matches
    for(size_t i = 0; i < keywordVector.size(); ++i) {
        if(keywordVector[i] == textWord) {
            countVector[i]++;//Found a match, increment the count
        }
    }
}
```

### Is that all there is?

No! The above method should work fine for small programs but things become problematic when the number of keywords becomes large and/or the number of words in `text_file.txt` becomes large.

Imagine this. Your `keywords_file.txt` becomes very large since it stores all the words in the English Oxford Dictionary and has around a million words. The first part of reading in the keywords would be fine since we require it anyway. But the next part is where the problems start. Imagine all the words in your `text_file.txt` were the word `zebra`. Now while searching for `zebra` in this list, you would have to go through that while loop ***every time for each word***. If there are a billion words in your `text_file.txt` then you would end up doing a million iterations for each word that you read and the total iterations would be 1billion X 1 million = 1 quadrillion iterations (1 followed by 15 zeroes). This is too big. Your program would complete in a very long time. Assuming each iteration takes 1 nanosecond, then total time would be 1 million seconds (`10^15* 10^-9`) which is `((1000000/60)/60)/24` = around 11.5 days!! Surely that is not acceptable!

We realize that the basic problem is that we have to search the entire loop every time we read in a word from `text_file.txt`. Only if there was a way to just *lookup* the word in the `keywordVector` directly *without* having to iterate over the entire vector each and every time.

This is exactly what `map` data structure helps with. These [data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) use a [`hash-function`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to quickly lookup things in a collection. They store what is called Key-Value pairs and you use the `key` to lookup its `value`.

e.g. if we have something like

```
{ 101: "Alice", 202: "Bob", 303: "Charlie"}
```

Then 101 is the *key* and `Alice` is the *value* of that key, 202 is the *key*, `Bob` is the *value* etc.

In the C++ STL there are 2 data structures that are build upon this concept [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). As the names suggest, the first one stores the keys in no particular order but the second one stores them in a sorted way.

Given this very basic intro to maps, we can see how this might be helpful for our case. We don't need to store the words from `keyword_file.txt` in any particular order. So we can use `std::unordered_map`, and use the `keyword` as the `key` for this map. We'll store the number of times that word appears as the `value` of this `key`. Here's some code:

```
/* Create a map to store key-value pairs of
    string and int, where each string is a keyword
    from the keywords_file.txt
*/
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> keywordMap;
std::string keyword;
while(keywordFile>>std::ws>>keyword) {
    //Initialize each word's count to 0
    keywordMap[keyword] = 0;
}

std::string textWord;
while(textFile>>std::ws>>textWord) {
    /*We do a find for the textWord in the map.
        This find isn't a linear loop like thing (unlike vector)
        but uses hashing to quickly look up if textWord exists in the
        map or not
    */
    if(keywordMap.find(textWord) != end(keywordMap)) {
        //If it exists, then we can just directly increment the count
        keywordMap[textWord]++;
    }
}
```

Using our time calculations, this time around the lookup of a billion words from the `text_file.txt` would each take up only in the order of a few nano-seconds since the [`unordered_map.find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) has an average case constant time complexity, unlike the earlier approach's linear complexity.

[image: Complexity]

So for a billion words, it takes an order of a billion nano-seconds which is just 1 second! Imagine the drastic difference in the times. The earlier method took days and this takes seconds. Hashing is a *very* powerful concept and finds applications in a lot of problems.

### *Followup*

Here's the [full code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d195fe924f6301a8), if you want to use it. This is a basic solution to finding the frequency of words in a file. Since you're beginning out in C++, I'd suggest you take your time to read in-depth into all the data structures used here and use this example to build upon your understanding. Also, if complexity is new to you, please do acquaint yourself with the topic.

Comment: You may also use some new APIs introduced in c++17

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Which APIs are you referring to?